# Javascript cursor: sequence of events

Tags: javascript, ajax, cursor

I have been searching but can't find anything relevant to my issue. I need to change the cursor when a user initiates an action so they don't shotgun the request.

The statement to change the cursor is simple enough, but I can't get it to fall into sequence correctly. My cursor doesn't change until the function completes. I can see this by commenting out the statement to return the cursor to normal behavior.

I want the cursor to go to wait and stay that way until the call tot he ajax function is done, then return to normal.

```
// wrapper to set wait cursor during ajax calls (the cursor change doesn't work, btw -- leaving it here so it can be fixed)
function loadForm(){
    setTimeout("document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].style.cursor = 'wait'",1);
    populateReadPage();
    setTimeout("document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].style.cursor = 'auto'", 1);
}

// configure calls to populate entire page: first string identifies the call, the second string identifies the custom function to implement
function populateReadPage(){
    setScreenObject("noncom","grid1");
    setScreenObject("cur_cert","grid2");
    setScreenObject("cur_hecm","grid3");
    setScreenObject("prev_cert","grid4");
    setScreenObject("prev_hecm","grid5");
}
```

Comment: Can't you use jquery? $('html').ajaxStart(function() {
    $(this).css({'cursor' : 'wait'});
}).ajaxStop(function() {
    $(this).css({'cursor' : 'default'});
});

Comment: They haven't accepted jquery as a standard here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript execution is single-threaded, so this is what happens when you execute the loadForm function:

1. `setTimeout(Action1,1)` :  Action1 is enqueued to be executed when the current (main) execution line finishes
2. `populateReadPage()` : This method is executed
3. `setTimeout(Action2,1)` : Again,  Action2 is enqueued to be executed when the current (main) execution line finishes.
4. Nothing else in the main line, `Action1` is executed
5. `Action2` is executed

**UPDATE**: After some research, it seems that the body style changes need a "pause" to be set, so I made it work with the following code:

```
function loadForm(){
  document.body.style.cursor = 'wait'; //sets the cursor to wait

  setTimeout(()=> { //enqueues the tasks
     populateReadPage();
     document.body.style.cursor = 'auto'; //once all is done, sets the regular pointer
  });
}
```

Just one thing: the cursor does not change until it moves, not sure why

Comment: That was the way I originally had the code. The symptoms are identical.
I removed the setTimeout calls and there was no change.

Comment: While I wait for my system to be available -

Can you explain the syntax?

I understand this:
    setTimeout(function(){//do stuff})}

what does the "()=>" do?

Comment: This does work. Thank you. (I had to add an artificial delay in the function to verify because my ajax calls are usually pretty fast.)

Comment: Regarding your question, the fat arrow syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Sigh! ... this doesn't work in IE (IE balks at the syntax and throws an error). I think I'm just going to give up on trying to do this.

Comment: I did not write it thinking of you using it as is, I wrote it just as a quick example so I used the shortest syntax. Arrow functions are nice but I usually transpile my code using Babel to ensure backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a topic switch ... I talked them into letting me use jQuery.

As I said at the top; all I want to do is set the cursor to "wait" then perform my async tasks then set it back to "auto". The code below is what I have now and it seems to work, (the paint doesn't happen until after the get) but the cursor never appears to change.

So far nothing (including the accepted answer) has worked for me.

This is my current code.

```
function setWait(){
    if(document.body.style.cursor = 'wait'){
        return this;
    }
}
function setAuto(){
    document.body.style.cursor = 'auto';
    return this;
}

function loadForm(){
    setWait();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.when(setScreenObject("prev_cert"),setScreenObject("noncom"), setScreenObject("cur_cert")).done(function() {parseResults();});
    setAuto();
    });
}

function setScreenObject(str1){
    // if "_user" exists use url 1 (counselor view), otherwise use url2 (hud/contractor view)
    if(document.getElementById('_user')){
        url="/clas/html/f17counselor_emp_req_db.cfc?method=getAgencyList&qCode=" + str1 + "&uid=" + document.getElementById('_user').value;
    } else {
        url="/clas/html/f17counselor_emp_req_db.cfc?method=getAgencyList&qCode=" + str1 + "&uid=&cid=" + document.getElementById('_identry').value;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : url,
        async : false,
        success : function (json) {
        switch(str1) {
            case "noncom":
                noncom = json;
            break;
            case "cur_cert":
                cur_cert = json;
            break;
            case "prev_cert":
                prev_cert = json;
            break;
            default:
                sysFault = true;
                displayError();
            }
        },
        error : function () {
            sysFault = true;
            displayError();
            },
        });
}
```